# Error al cargar el archivo

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con archivos, pero me salen dos errores

> For input string: "Eduardo" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "Eduardo"

antes de eso me arrojaba un error de NoSuchElementException pero ya lo solucione

Este es mi codigo para cargar el archivo

```
public void cargar_txt(){
    File ruta = new File(ruta_txt);
    String linea = null;
    int ln = 0;
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(ruta);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        dc = null;
        while((linea = br.readLine()) != null){
            ln++;
            try{
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linea, ", ");
                while(st.hasMoreElements() && st.nextToken() != null){
                    dc = new DatosCliente();
                    dc.setCuenta(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
                    dc.setNombre(st.nextToken());
                    dc.setPaterno(st.nextToken());
                    dc.setMaterno(st.nextToken());
                    dc.setSaldo(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
                    dc.setPassword(st.nextToken());
                    pb.AgregarCliente(dc);
                }
            }catch(NoSuchElementException ex){
                System.out.println(String.format("NSE in %d: %s", ln, linea));
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        mensaje("Error al cargar el archivo: " + e.getMessage());
        mensaje("Error: " + e);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el contenido del archivo?

Comment: @Guz tiene razón, podrias poner el contenido del archivo? por el error que te sale pareciera como si estuviera tratando de convertir la cadena `Eduardo` a un tipo de dato int, por eso el `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

Comment: @Luis9724, me parece que el primer token posiblemente tiene un valor numérico pero estas leyendolo al realizar la comparación en el while. te recomiendo unicamente usar: while(st.hasMoreElements()){

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el problema no es la carga del archivo, **el problema es que al obtener el primer token que obtienes al separar por ", " no es de tipo numérico**,

```
 dc.setCuenta(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
```

al tratar de convertirlo a valor entero, cuando no es numérico provoca el error:

> For input string:....  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:....

de hecho el valor del token es "Eduardo".

---

Te recomiendo evitar leer el primer token en esta linea mediante `nextToken()` y ùnicamente usar `hasMoreElements()` para determinar si se encuentra un token disponible:

```
while(st.hasMoreElements() /* && st.nextToken() != null*/){
...
...
```

esto puede ser causa del problema si es que el primer token es el que deseas convertir a entero.